# Objective C Recursive Calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion

I'm trying to continuously check the readings from the accelerometer before the camera takes a picture.  I have a function that takes a picture, and at the beggining of that function I check whether the accelerometer readings are too high.  If they are, I'd like to call the function again to check if acceleration has stopped.

```
- (void)takePicture {

    if (accelerating == YES) {
        [self takePicture];
    }

    else {
        // Code that takes picture
    }
}
```

I guess the problem I'm having is the function gets recursively called too many times that I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)".  How can I fix this recursive calling problem?

Comment: Add the code where you declared `accelerating`.

Comment: please paste the code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `[self takePicture]` that will end up retrying *immediately*, which is useless and wasteful, as you're not even giving your application any time to receive additional accelerometer events. The value of `accelerating` will probably never change before you run out of stack.

What you probably want to do here is have the method called a fraction of a second later, e.g.

```
[self performSelector: @selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.01];
return;
```

This will have the event loop call your method again 10 milliseconds (0.01 second) later.

Comment: Then again, this schedules a ton of timers in the current Run Loop.  It would be far more efficient to call `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` and refactor this into 2 methods.

Comment: @CodaFi: That's a good point. Alternatively, it'd probably make sense to take measures (in the UI) to deactivate the "take a picture" button until a picture has been successfully taken.

Comment: It seems like this would all just boil down to a while-loop anyhow.  No need to get high-level.  `while(accelerating){} [self takePicture];` should work great (if "blocking-ly").

Comment: @CodaFi: You're assuming that `accelerating` is being updated by another thread. It probably is not.

Comment: @duskwuff then he could re-write it as BOOLean getter (preferably in C, for less overhead).

Comment: A while loop is going to block the run loop running in that thread, if any.

Comment: -1 for `performSelector:`. It seems like a bad architecture and unclear code for me. It's better to make `wantsToTakePicture` (or smth like that) property/ivar and read it when `accelerating` is set to `NO`.

Answer (score 3):

A potential better way of implementing this would be by overriding the setter for accelerating to something like this:

```
- (void)setAccelerating:(BOOL)accelerating {
    _accelerating = accelerating;
    if (accelerating) // maybe some more conditions, but you get the idea
        [self takePicture];
}
```